# How to get loaderManager.initLoader working within a fragment?

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

I've made the changes suggested by the most kind kris larson, and I'm now not returning the right type from onCreateLoader

```
return new StoriesLoader(getContext(), uriBuilder.toString());
```

StoriesLoader:

```
import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.content.Context;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Loads a list of news stories by using an AsyncTask to perform the
 * network request to the given URL.
 */
public class StoriesLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<NewsStory>> {

    /** Tag for log messages */
    private static final String LOG_TAG = StoriesLoader.class.getName();

    /** Query URL */
    private String mUrl;

    /**
     * Constructs a new {@link StoriesLoader}.
     *
     * @param context of the activity
     * @param url to load data from
     */
    public StoriesLoader(Context context, String url) {
        super(context);
        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        forceLoad();
    }

    /**
     * This is on a background thread.
     */
    @Override
    public List<NewsStory> loadInBackground() {
        if (mUrl == null) {
            return null;
        }

        // Perform the network request, parse the response, and extract a list of news stories.
        List<NewsStory> newsStories = QueryUtils.fetchNewsStoryData(mUrl);
        return newsStories;
    }
}
```

I think I'm right to use an AsyncTaskLoader, but I don't get how to wrap / cast what is returned so it's a

```
Loader<List<NewsStory>>
```

Is my thinking wrong?  Do I have to ditch the AsyncTaskLoader?
~~~

StoriesLoader returns List, from

```
    /**
 * This is on a background thread.
 */
@Override
public List<NewsStory> loadInBackground() {
    if (mUrl == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // Perform the network request, parse the response, and extract a list of earthquakes.
    List<NewsStory> newsStories = QueryUtils.fetchNewsStoryData(mUrl);
    return newsStories;
}
```

I've tried these, to no avail:

```
return new Loader<(new StoriesLoader(getContext(), uriBuilder.toString()))>();
return new Loader<>(new StoriesLoader(getContext(), uriBuilder.toString()));
```

If you're out there Kris, your corrections are well appreciated.

~~~~~~~~~
Studio is complaining

> Wrong 3rd argument type. Found:
>   'com.newsreader.guardian.guardiantech.ListOfStoriesFragment',
>   required:
>   'android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks'

When met with this

```
loaderManager.initLoader(mPage, null, this);
```

I believe it wants a way to reference the loader callbacks as the third parameter, it needs a map to where they are, is this right?

I'm using the Loader in a fragment so that has derailed it.  I've tried changing the third parameter to getActivity(), getContext(), tried ListOfStoriesFragment, all to no avail.

The Fragment does implement the LoaderCallbacks interface - the callbacks are beneath it, so why doesn't it work?

I tried Android Studio's suggested fixes.  Implement v4.app.LoadManager callbacks, but that broke a world of stuff.

How do I fix this?  Can I fix this by importing something different?
Apologies for the question.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.newsreader.guardian.guardiantech.BuildConfig.API_KEY;

/**
 * Initiates a loader to get JSON from The Guardian
 * updates UI with info when the data has returned
 */

public class ListOfStoriesFragment extends Fragment
        implements android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<NewsStory>> {
    /** String for tabs */
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
    private int mPage;

    private static final String TAG = ListOfStoriesFragment.class.getName();

    /** URL for earthquake data from the USGS dataset */
    private static final String GUARDIAN_REQUEST_URL =
            "http://content.guardianapis.com/search";

    /**
     * Constant value for the news story loader ID. We can choose any integer.
     * This really only comes into play if you're using multiple loaders.
     */
    private static final int NEWSSTORY_LOADER_ID = 1;

    /** Adapter for the list of newsStories */
    private NewsStoryAdapter mAdapter;

    /** TextView that is displayed when the list is empty */
    private TextView mEmptyStateTextView;

    /** more tabs stuff */
    public static ListOfStoriesFragment newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        ListOfStoriesFragment fragment = new ListOfStoriesFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    /** needed for tabs?! */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stories, container, false);

        // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
        ListView newsStoryListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        newsStoryListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);

        // Create a new adapter that takes an empty list of NewsStory as input
        mAdapter = new NewsStoryAdapter(getContext(), new ArrayList<NewsStory>());

        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface
        newsStoryListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        // Get a reference to the ConnectivityManager to check state of network connectivity
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // Get details on the currently active default data network
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // If there is a network connection, fetch data
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.
            LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();

            // Initialize the loader. Pass in the int ID constant defined above and pass in null for
            // the bundle. Pass in this activity for the LoaderCallbacks parameter (which is valid
            // because this activity implements the LoaderCallbacks interface).
            //loaderManager.initLoader(NEWSSTORY_LOADER_ID, null, this);

            // number the loaderManager with mPage as may be requesting up to three lots of JSON for each tab
            loaderManager.initLoader(mPage, null, this);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, display error
            // First, hide loading indicator so error message will be visible
            View loadingIndicator = rootView.findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
            loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Update empty state with no connection error message
            mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_internet_connection);
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<NewsStory>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        String searchTerm;
        switch(mPage) {
            case 0:
                searchTerm = "windows";
                break;
            case 1:
                searchTerm = "android";
                break;
            default:
                searchTerm = "android wear";
        }

        Uri baseUri = Uri.parse(GUARDIAN_REQUEST_URL);
        Uri.Builder uriBuilder = baseUri.buildUpon();

        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("q", searchTerm);
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("api-key", API_KEY);
        uriBuilder.build();

        Log.wtf(TAG, uriBuilder.toString());

        return new StoriesLoader(getContext(), uriBuilder.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<NewsStory>> loader, List<NewsStory> newsStories) {
        // Hide loading indicator because the data has been loaded
        View loadingIndicator = getView().findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Set empty state text to display "No stories found."
        mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_news_stories);

        // Clear the adapter of previous newsStories
        mAdapter.clear();

        // If there is a valid list of {@link NewsStory}s, then add them to the adapter's
        // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.
        if (newsStories != null && !newsStories.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter.addAll(newsStories);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<NewsStory>> loader) {
        // Loader reset, so we can clear out our existing data.
        mAdapter.clear();
    }


}
```

Comment: you may want to use `android.support.v4.content.loader` ?

Comment: return Loader<List<NewsStory>>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The Fragment does implement the LoaderCallbacks interface - the callbacks are beneath it, so why doesn't it work?

Because you are mixing support library classes with platform classes.

`android.content.Loader` is not compatible with `android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager`

The line

```
           LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
```

is returning a `android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager` so for

```
           loaderManager.initLoader(mPage, null, this);
```

to compile, your fragment will need to implement `android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`, not `android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`.

I've had this problem multiple times.

I will assume you want the support library classes.

Change

```
import android.content.Loader;
```

to

```
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
```

Change

```
public class ListOfStoriesFragment extends Fragment
        implements android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<NewsStory>> {
```

to

```
public class ListOfStoriesFragment extends Fragment
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<NewsStory>> {
```

and that should fix your problem.

---

Make sure `StoriesLoader` extends `android.support.v4.app.Loader` and not `android.app.Loader`. Check your import statements.

Comment: Whatever else is breaking after you make these changes, add details to your post and I will address them.

Comment: Cheers @kris larson, glad I'm not alone.  Going to do some more reading on Loaders, but would love your help with how to fix 

return new Loader<(new StoriesLoader(getContext(), uriBuilder.toString()))>();

from onCreateLoader

Comment: Make sure `StoriesLoader` extends `android.support.v4.app.Loader` and not `android.app.Loader`.  Check your import statements.

Comment: Humph, it actually extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<NewsStory>> , which I presume is best for network requests / fetching json.  Just doesn't return a Loader rather the NewsStory list.

Comment: I've included it above.  The docs say it's a class of android.support.v4.content.Loader, which is what Android Studio complains it's needing to return.  I'm not fully understanding.

Comment: I messed up.  What I should have said was: Make sure `StoriesLoader` extends `android.support.v4.app.AsyncTaskLoader` and not `android.app.AsyncTaskLoader`. Check your import statements.

Comment: Just change `import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;` to `import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Now you see why I had this problem so many times.  You need the support fragment to get the support loader manager, and the fragment needs to implement the support callbacks and the loader needs to extend the support Loader subclass, whichever that is.

Comment: you're a God!  in StoriesLoader I extend android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader<List<NewsStory>> and job done.  So many similar libraries and interfaces :)  Thanks kris, so nice to have this issue cracked.  Learning lesson: look at Android Studio complaint, try modifying either imports or extends to 'what is required'.

Comment: Use LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(0, null, this) when you are implementing LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> with importing import androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager