# AsyncTask Loader & LoaderManager.init() requires callback for third Argument. Which LoaderManager should be used?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, asynctaskloader

```
LoaderManager loaderManager = getSupportLoaderManager();
Loader loader = loaderManager.getLoader(SEARCH_LOADER);
if(loader==null)
{
  loaderManager.initLoader(SEARCH_LOADER,bundle,this);//SEARCH_LOADER-20
}
```

The Below is  Hover errorMessage :

> //**Required**:android.app.LoaderManager
>   **Found**:android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager

If im Importing  android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager But activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks it shows error.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41267966/8919244)

Answer (score 1):

Changing All imported Packages lead Solution:

Before:
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;

import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;

import android.support.v4.content.Loader;

After:

import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;

import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;

import android.support.v4.content.Loader;